# Is it possible to take a log of whole script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have deployed a post-receive hook script and I want to get whole output logs in a file as a block starting with date. I have tried one method but it take line by line log, meaning I have to put that command against every line to get the log. Is there any way to get the whole script log once starting with date?

Script file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
any_command | ts '[%F %T]' >> /home/Man/Man_log.log
second_command | ts '[%F %T]' >> /home/Man/Man_log.log
third_command | ts '[%F %T]' >> /home/Man/Man_log.log
```

see i have to put this line `| ts '[%F %T]' >> /home/Man/Man_log.log` against every command to get log. And I have 90 lines, so it is not a perfect way to do this. I need an efficient way, like only one line in my script which takes the output of the whole script as log and stores it to another Man_log.log file starting with the date.

What i want is similar to this.

```
#!/bin/bash
ts '[%F %T]' >> /home/Man/Man_log.log #a command which can store logs of every command below this to a separate file starting with date
any_command
second_command
third_command
```

Comment: What is that last monospaced block? Is it desired output - if so, why does it start with a command?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to  modify your script to print the date everytime is called:

```
#!/bin/sh

date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"

# your commands below
...
```

if you can't modify the script then you could group your commands for example:

```
(date && anycommand) >> out.log
```

Grouping a (list of commands) in parenthesis causes them to be executed as if they were a single unit. "[sub-shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138498/53084)"

Comment: No actually i don't want to group the whole commands in parenthesis.

Comment: I have use this technique and it works like charm (https://serverfault.com/questions/103501/how-can-i-fully-log-all-bash-scripts-actions) but now their is one issue it overwrite the log file means everytime i run a script it remove the previous log and add new.

Comment: @Pasha the `>>` should append instead of overwriting or you could use `| tee -a out.log` the -a will append

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is the script that should give us some logs:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "log_line1
log_line2
log_line3
log_line4"
```

And let's call it `script.sh`.

Running it as `./script.sh | printf "%(%F)T {\n$(cat)\n}" >> Man_log.log`, content of `Man_log.log` will be:

```
2018-05-04 {
log_line1
log_line2
log_line3
log_line4
}
```

Let me now explain what exactly the pipe does.

- `%(%F)T` is replaced with current date in **YEAR**-**MONTH**-**DAY** format
- `$(cat)` are the logs that are output of `./script.sh`. In general it is data received as standard input. 
  Basically `./script.sh` writes it's logs to standard output. The pipe then passes that standard output to standard input of `echo`. Running `cat` without parameters is the same as `cat /dev/stdin`.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use `printf` with the `%(format)T` modifier (bash 4.2 or later) rather than `echo` with the `date` external program.

Comment: @cdarke thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer with your proposal.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions. Do i write this whole command every time in a shell ./script.sh | printf "%(%F)T {\n$(cat)\n}" >> Man_log.log

Comment: Well, yes. But if you want this kind of logging every single time you run the script this it's kinda boring. If you don't want to change output of your script you can keep `printf "%(%F)T {\n$(cat)\n}"` as separate script e.g. `wrap_with_date.sh` so you can call your script with `./script.sh | ./wrap_with_date.sh >> Man_log.log`.

Comment: @dmadic i have edited my question hope now you get it what actually i want.

Comment: Ahaaa, you want each log line to be prefixed with date and time?